# GruntFile returns [object, Object]

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

I am using a foundation/jekyll [boilerplate](https://github.com/daigofuji/jekyll-foundation-5-starter).

Whenever I run grunt, it only returns the following in my style.css

```
[object Object]
```

It should have processed the scss from the foundation files.

Here is the gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

sass: {
  options: {
    includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    },
    files: {
      'css/style.css': 'scss/style.scss'
    }        
  }
},

watch: {
  grunt: { files: ['Gruntfile.js'] },

  sass: {
    files: 'scss/**/*.scss',
    tasks: ['sass']
  }
}
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['build','watch']);
}
```

The only thing I had to do was npm install node-sass.
I ran grunt and the only code in my style.css was [object, Object]

edit: ran `npm install grunt-sass`,
css now compiles nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there's an error with [recent](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/170) [version](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/170) of `node-sass` where in error situations `node-sass` pipes `[object Object]` instead of failing and showing a proper stacktrace.

Your `Gruntfile` worked fine for me in a reduced test case, so validate your `scss` files before running the task.

Also, update to the newest `node-sass/grunt-sass` with `npm install node-sass -save-dev`, as it doesn't seem to behave that way (but throws the proper error instead).

Comment: Wow, it did the trick. I ran npm install grunt-sass and the sass compiles into the css file. Thanks!