# Grunt outputs [object Object] from sass

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, npm, bower

I have grunt running in OS X, through PHPStorm 8's terminal.

I just did a fresh install of node.js and bower and grunt. I have done this on two other OS X machines without any hassles.

For some reason, grunt is compiling my SCSS file to:

```
[object Object]
```

It works on my desktop and other laptop, running the same versions of everything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GruntFile returns \[object, Object\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711385/gruntfile-returns-object-object)